# error optim birnbaum sanders distribution fnpar

Tags: r, r-markdown

I don't know why I get an error message when I'm trying to use optim in R.

I have following data:

```
x <- c(6.0401209,  7.2888217,  0.4868070,
       1.1699703, 51.5998419, 11.8766734,
       2.3873264, 16.9583702, 21.6142835,
       0.3133089,  3.4178360,  4.4367427,
       2.0205100, 10.5798884,  0.4890031,
       1.6734176, 10.2809820,  6.4705424,
       5.6801965,  0.9438700)
```

And following log-likelihood function:

```
log.lik.bs <- function(gamma, betha, z){
  n <- length(z)
  - n * log(gamma) - n * log(2*sqrt(2*2*pi)) - sum(log(z)) + sum(log(sqrt(z/betha)) + sqrt(betha/z)) - (1/2*gamma^2) * sum((sqrt(z/betha) - sqrt(betha/z))^2)
}
```

What I'm trying to do is following:

```
optim(c(2, 6), log.lik.bs, control=list(fnscale=-1), x=x, method="BFGS")$par
```

But I get an error message:

```
Error in fn(par, ...) : 
  unused argument (x = c(6.04012089885228, 7.28882174812723, 0.486806990614708, 1.1699703323488, 51.5998418613029, 11.8766733963947, 2.38732637900487, 16.9583701851951, 21.6142834611592, 0.313308870127425, 3.41783600439905, 4.43674270859797, 2.02051001746263, 10.5798883747597, 0.489003100259996, 1.67341757119939, 10.2809820486722, 6.4705423816332, 5.68019649178721, 0.943869996033357))
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not quite clear which parameters you are trying to optimize. I assume you want to optimize `log.lik.bs` with respect  to `gamma` and `betha` for given `z` with initial values 2 and 6. In that case you have two errors in your code:

- `log.lik.bs` is expecting an argument named `z` but you are providing an argument `x`. That is the error you are getting. Fix: `z = x`
- When using `optim` your target function must take a *single* argument for the parameters. From `?optim`:

  > A function to be minimized (or maximized), with first argument the vector of parameters over which minimization is to take place. It should return a scalar result.

Combining this I get:

```
x <- c(6.0401209,  7.2888217,  0.4868070,
       1.1699703, 51.5998419, 11.8766734,
       2.3873264, 16.9583702, 21.6142835,
       0.3133089,  3.4178360,  4.4367427,
       2.0205100, 10.5798884,  0.4890031,
       1.6734176, 10.2809820,  6.4705424,
       5.6801965,  0.9438700)
log.lik.bs <- function(x, z){
  gamma <- x[1]
  betha <- x[2]
  n <- length(z)
  - n * log(gamma) - n * log(2*sqrt(2*2*pi)) - sum(log(z)) 
      + sum(log(sqrt(z/betha)) + sqrt(betha/z)) 
      - (1/2*gamma^2) * sum((sqrt(z/betha) - sqrt(betha/z))^2)
}
optim(c(2, 6), log.lik.bs, control=list(fnscale=-1), z=x, method="BFGS")$par
```

Unfortunately this still throws an error:

```
Error in optim(c(2, 6), log.lik.bs, control = list(fnscale = -1), z = x,  : 
  non-finite finite-difference value [1]
```

In addition there are several warnings that NaNs where introduced by `sqrt` and `log`. So my interpretation of your question might be wrong. After all, the function goes to infinity as `gamma` goes to zero.